# Articles to use with instruments

Tags: usage

Could anyone tell me which of these is correct?
The intro to this song is played on A guitar
                                   OR
The intro to this song is played on THE guitar.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: You can also say ..."is played on guitar."

Comment: Or even " . . . is played on (the) guitars," if there is more than one. In order to answer the question, we would need to know the *exact* context in which it was being said and what specific meaning was meant to be imparted.

Answer (score 1):

Each of these

- > The intro to this song is played on guitar
- > The intro to this song is played on a guitar
- > The intro to this song is played on the guitar

is grammatical and acceptable. Out of context, they also mean the same thing, namely that guitar is the instrument the song’s intro is written for and typically played on.

In particular contexts there might be nuances to each. For example, consider a particular performance with a particular band with a particular (limited) set of instruments, and in particular only one guiter. In this situation, “the guitar” emphasizes that it is the only one—and that while the guitar is being used for this intro, it cannot also be used for something else at the same time. (This distinction might be clearer if we were saying something like “The rhythm section of this song is played on the guitar”—so if the only guitar is playing rhythm, you cannot also have a lead guitar for the song.)

But such situations would be pretty unusual, and the sentence would only be read that way if it was already established that we were dealing with a single guitar. And as nnnnnn points out, reordering it to say “the guitar will play the rhythm part,” would be far clearer for emphasizing the single guitar.

So in almost-all cases, the three mean the same thing. In my experience, using *the* seems ever-so-slightly the most common here, but none of these are unusual.

Comment: I think your specific example is, as you said, pretty unusual. I wouldn't normally take "played on the guitar" to mean that there is necessarily only one guitar in use, nor would I take "the rhythm part is played on the guitar" to mean that there can't also be a lead/melody part played on guitar at the same time. If it were phrased the other way around - "the guitar will play the rhythm part" - *then* I would take it that there isn't also another guitar playing the melody at the same time.

Comment: @nnnnnn Correct, that would only be clear if it was already established that we are dealing with a single-guitar situation. But you’re right that the reordering is superior even in that case. I’ll update the answer with that.

Answer (score -1):

Think of the meaning of the following:

Astronauts landed on moon.

Astronauts landed on a moon.

The Astronauts landed on the moon.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, however; in fact, it is essentially a restatement of the question itself. Not every participant here is a native speaker of English, and many languages do not have articles, or have different parameters for definiteness from English,

Comment: This definitely doesn't answer the question: the Moon is special because there is only one of it. -1.

Comment: @Col Only one moon? Exactly what the Venutians *want* us to think!

Comment: @JimReynolds: There are many moons. There is only one Moon!